# Is it possible to create a dropdown controlwrapper from values in a row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface, google-visualization

Is it possible to create a category filter that gets it's values from certain parts of the horizontal axis of a table. For instance in a table:

```
Heading 1|Heading 2|Heading 3|Heading 4|Heading 5  
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
AValue  1|AValue  2|AValue  3|AValue  4|AValue  5  
BValue  1|BValue  2|BValue  3|BValue  4|BValue  5  
CValue  1|CValue  2|CValue  3|CValue  4|CValue  5
```

Instead of having a dropdown with Heading1's Values, is it possible create dropdown with only Heading3,Heading4,Heading5 as values and then the chart data displayed is only the data underneath the particular heading selected?

```
var CountryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({ 
        controlType: 'CategoryFilter', 
        containerId: 'control3', 
        options: { 
            filterColumnLabel: 'Location', 
            ui: { 
                labelStacking: 'vertical', 
                allowTyping: false, 
                allowMultiple: true, 
                caption: 'Country', 
                label: '' 
            } 
        } 
    });
```

**EDIT:**
Here is an image of the data table, I wish to be able to filter by Male, Female and Total through the dropdown.
[image: Data Table Layout]

CSV function for geochart:

```
function drawVisualization() { 

$.get("Data_Actual_V2.csv", function(csvString) { 
        var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
          for (var i = 1; i < arrayData[0].length; i++) {       
          $("select").append("<option value='" + i + "'>" + arrayData[0][i] + "</option");
          }

        $("#range option[value='1']").attr("selected","selected");
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

var geoChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({ 
    chartType: 'GeoChart', 
    containerId: 'chart1', 
    options: { 
        title: 'A', 
        displayMode: 'regions', 
        width: 1000, 
        datalessRegionColor: 'C0C0C0', 
        colorAxis: { 
            values: [0, 12.5, 25, 37.5, 50, 62.5, 75, 87.5, 100], 
            colors: ['#3366FF','#33CCCC', '#00FFFF', '#CCFFFF', '#00FF00', '#FFFF99','#FFCC00','#FF9900','#FF0000'], 
            minValue: 0, 
            maxValue: 100, 
        } 
    }, 
    view: { // Defines data to show in geoChart 
        columns: [0, 4] 
    } 
});
```

**EDIT2:** I have the chart working with the single filter as first asked, but intially had more than one filter available. eg, select country, then select by method above. An example of how I did this before getting the above working is below, but how can I incorporate this with the method described in the fiddle below?

```
    var CountryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({ 
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter', 
    containerId: 'control3', 
    options: { 
        filterColumnLabel: 'Location', 
        ui: { 
            labelStacking: 'vertical', 
            allowTyping: false, 
            allowMultiple: true, 
            caption: 'Country', 
            label: '' 
        } 
    } 
}); 
var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')); 

dashboard.bind([CountryPicker, GenderPicker, slider2],[geoChart]). // consolidated all of the bind calls 
// Draw the dashboard 

draw(data);
```

Comment: Is something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/WaUu2/) what you are looking for?

Comment: @asgallant yes, that is it, however how would I implement it if I am getting my data from a csv. see above edit

Comment: It should work the same way - just use your csv code and `arrayToDataTable` call instead of manually building the DataTable like the example.

Comment: @asgallant I got it kind of working but I can't work out how I can get a second filter to also have influence on the state of the chart displayed.

Comment: Like for instance if I wanted to have a normal filter for displaying specific countries only.